# XML - Is there an easier way

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Title doesnt explain what this is but i don't really know what to put;

The code works i just wanted to know if there was a better way.

```
string OrePrice = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002187";

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(OrePrice);
XmlNodeList xnod0 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 34]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod1 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 34]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod2 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 35]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod3 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 35]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod4 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 36]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod5 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 36]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod6 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 37]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod7 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 37]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod8 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 38]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod9 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 38]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod10 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 39]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod11 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 39]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod12 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 40]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod13 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 40]/sell");
XmlNodeList xnod14 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 11399]/buy");
XmlNodeList xnod15 = xdoc.SelectNodes("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = 11399]/sell");
foreach (XmlElement xnod in xnod0)
{
    TriPrAmarB.Text = xnod["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode0 in xnod1)
{
    TriPrAmarS.Text = xnode0["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode4 in xnod4)
{
    MexPrAmarB.Text = xnode4["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode5 in xnod5)
{
    MexPrAmarS.Text = xnode5["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode6 in xnod6)
{
    IsoPrAmarB.Text = xnode6["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode7 in xnod7)
{
    IsoPrAmarS.Text = xnode7["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode2 in xnod2)
{
    PyrPrAmarB.Text = xnode2["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode3 in xnod3)
{
    PyrPrAmarS.Text = xnode3["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode8 in xnod8)
{
    NocPrAmarB.Text = xnode8["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode9 in xnod9)
{
    NocPrAmarS.Text = xnode9["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode12 in xnod12)
{
    MegPrAmarB.Text = xnode12["max"].InnerText;
}
foreach (XmlElement xnode13 in xnod13)
{
    MegPrAmarS.Text = xnode13["max"].InnerText;
}
```

as you can see im using a API link to get an XML file that i want to "cut down" but it holds mutliple ID nodes that i need to seperate and take a element value from it and put that value in to text/label boxes. at the moment im doing it like this(see code). it's messy and stressing me out. is there a better way?? or am i going about this all wrong?

For those who don't want to load the weblink here it is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    -<evec_api method="marketstat_xml" version="2.0">     
    -<marketstat>    
    -<type id="34">    
    -<buy>   
    <volume>3457195520</volume>    
    <avg>5.44</avg>    
    <max>5.83</max>    
    <min>4.18</min>    
    <stddev>0.61</stddev>    
    <median>5.51</median>    
    <percentile>5.82</percentile>    
    </buy>   
    -<sell>    
    <volume>3243443787</volume>    
    <avg>6.47</avg>    
    <max>15.82</max>    
    <min>5.87</min>
    <stddev>1.80</stddev>    
    <median>6.20</median>    
    <percentile>6.05</percentile>    
    </sell>   
    -<all>    
    <volume>6800639307</volume>    
    <avg>5.86</avg>    
    <max>15.82</max>    
    <min>0.20</min>    
    <stddev>1.87</stddev>    
    <median>5.82</median>    
    <percentile>3.60</percentile>    
    </all>
    </type>        
    -<type id="35">    
    -<buy>
     <volume>616253967</volume>    
    <avg>9.98</avg>    
    <max>10.70</max>
    <min>6.34</min>    
    <stddev>1.24</stddev>    
    <median>10.48</median>    
    <percentile>10.70</percentile>    
    </buy>   
    -<sell>    
    <volume>657965395</volume>    
    <avg>14.21</avg>    
    <max>24.00</max>    
    <min>11.44</min>    
    <stddev>6.01</stddev>    
    <median>11.68</median>    
    <percentile>11.44</percentile>    
    </sell> 
    -<all>    
    <volume>1274219362</volume>    
    <avg>12.17</avg>    
    <max>24.00</max>    
    <min>6.34</min>    
    <stddev>6.14</stddev>    
    <median>11.44</median>    
    <percentile>7.82</percentile>    
    </all>    
    </type>
   -<type id="36">
    -<buy>    
    <volume>322291783</volume>    
    <avg>53.35</avg>    
    <max>56.00</max>    
    <min>38.26</min>    
    <stddev>4.23</stddev>    
    <median>55.25</median>    
    <percentile>55.99</percentile>    
    </buy>  
    -<sell>
     <volume>580953174</volume>    
    <avg>63.29</avg>    
    <max>89.40</max>
    <min>59.00</min>    
    <stddev>7.81</stddev>    
    <median>60.44</median>    
    <percentile>59.60</percentile>    
    </sell>
    -<all>    
    <volume>903244957</volume>    
    <avg>59.74</avg>    
    <max>89.40</max>    
    <min>38.26</min>    
    <stddev>8.48</stddev>    
    <median>59.82</median>    
    <percentile>43.37</percentile>    
    </all>
    </type>
    -<type id="37">
    -<buy>    
    <volume>147215461</volume>    
    <avg>92.36</avg>    
    <max>96.68</max>
    <min>38.40</min>    
    <stddev>13.23</stddev>    
    <median>96.64</median>    
    <percentile>96.67</percentile>    
    </buy>
    -<sell>    
    <volume>213867507</volume>    
    <avg>114.33</avg>
    <max>280.00</max>    
    <min>100.00</min>    
    <stddev>40.85</stddev>    
    <median>102.29</median>    
    <percentile>100.93</percentile>    
    </sell>
    -<all>    
    <volume>371082968</volume>    
    <avg>102.82</avg>
    <max>280.00</max>    
    <min>10.64</min>    
    <stddev>40.74</stddev>    
    <median>100.97</median>    
    <percentile>47.42</percentile>    
    </all>    
    </type>  
    -<type id="38">
    -<buy>    
    <volume>37059521</volume>    
    <avg>438.61</avg>
    <max>456.73</max>    
    <min>355.00</min>    
    <stddev>32.35</stddev>    
    <median>452.53</median>    
    <percentile>456.73</percentile>    
    </buy>
    -<sell>    
    <volume>41961165</volume>    
    <avg>536.59</avg>    
    <max>650.00</max>    
    <min>469.00</min>    
    <stddev>54.90</stddev>    
    <median>513.63</median>    
    <percentile>469.00</percentile>    
    </sell>
    -<all>    
    <volume>79020686</volume>    
    <avg>490.64</avg>    
    <max>650.00</max>    
    <min>355.00</min>    
    <stddev>68.43</stddev>    
    <median>469.00</median>    
    <percentile>379.86</percentile>    
    </all>    
    </type>
    -<type id="39">    
        -<buy>

    <volume>17527906</volume>    
    <avg>1011.91</avg>
    <max>1267.00</max>    
    <min>751.00</min>    
    <stddev>163.64</stddev>    
    <median>991.85</median>    
    <percentile>1266.25</percentile>    
    </buy>
    -<sell>    
    <volume>11084558</volume>    
    <avg>1472.06</avg>    
    <max>1899.00</max>    
    <min>1428.98</min>
    <stddev>87.97</stddev>    
    <median>1470.38</median>    
    <percentile>1428.98</percentile>    
    </sell>
    -<all>    
    <volume>31612464</volume>    
    <avg>1101.04</avg>    
    <max>1899.00</max>    
    <min>251.01</min>    
    <stddev>259.73</stddev>    
    <median>1182.01</median>
    <percentile>251.01</percentile>    
    </all>   
    </type> 
    -<type id="40">
    -<buy>
     <volume>11218433</volume>   
    <avg>991.80</avg>    
    <max>1110.04</max>    
    <min>876.01</min>    
    <stddev>83.77</stddev>    
    <median>969.94</median>    
    <percentile>1110.03</percentile>    
    </buy>
    -<sell>    
    <volume>13324678</volume>    
    <avg>1298.68</avg>    
    <max>1842.00</max>    
    <min>1199.97</min>    
    <stddev>140.89</stddev>    
    <median>1228.95</median>    
    <percentile>1205.26</percentile>    
    </sell>        
    -<all>    
    <volume>24543111</volume>    
    <avg>1158.41</avg>    
    <max>1842.00</max>    
    <min>876.01</min>    
    <stddev>175.90</stddev>    
    <median>1206.00</median>    
    <percentile>888.68</percentile>    
    </all>
    </type>
    -<type id="11399">
    -<buy>    
    <volume>383592</volume>    
    <avg>9206.37</avg>    
    <max>11045.43</max>    
    <min>5510.66</min>    
    <stddev>1680.48</stddev>   
    <median>9100.05</median>    
    <percentile>11016.97</percentile>    
    </buy>   
    -<sell>    
    <volume>420217</volume>    
    <avg>11902.63</avg>    
    <max>17183.99</max>    
    <min>11150.99</min>    
    <stddev>1956.07</stddev>    
    <median>11488.00</median>    
    <percentile>11150.99</percentile>    
    </sell>  
    -<all>
     <volume>803809</volume>
        <avg>10615.93</avg>    
    <max>17183.99</max>    
    <min>5510.66</min>
     <stddev>2169.53</stddev>    
    <median>11150.99</median>    
    <percentile>5513.25</percentile>    
    </all>    
    </type>
    </marketstat>    
    </evec_api>
```

Comment: use `array`, your code forms some pattern

Comment: good idea, i'll give it ago, can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I would not like to maintain this code

Comment: why can't i just carry on with the searching.. something like:                 TriPrAmarB.Text = singlenode.Attributes["@id = 34/buy/max"].InnerText;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you just need to refactor your code into a few small helper methods and use those when setting your textboxes.  For example, something like this would allow you to easily get the value of any kind of stat from the xml based on the id, transaction type (buy or sell) and statistic type (max, min, avg, etc.):

```
enum TranType { Buy, Sell, All };
enum StatType { Volume, Avg, Max, Min, StdDev, Median, Percentile };

private static string GetStat(XmlDocument xdoc, int id, TranType tranType, StatType statType)
{
    string xpath = string.Format("/evec_api/marketstat/type[@id = {0}]/{1}/{2}", 
                   id, tranType.ToString().ToLower(), statType.ToString().ToLower());

    return GetFirstElementText(xdoc, xpath);
}

private static string GetFirstElementText(XmlDocument xdoc, string xpath)
{
    // Get the InnerText of the first XmlElement matching the xpath, if any (otherwise null)
    return xdoc.SelectNodes(xpath).Cast<XmlElement>().Select(x => x.InnerText).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Note: you will need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your code (if you don't already have it) for these helper methods to work.

With these helper methods in place, you can set your textboxes like this:

```
string OrePrice = "http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&minQ=1&typeid=35&minQ=1&typeid=36&minQ=1&typeid=37&minQ=1&typeid=38&minQ=1&typeid=39&minQ=1&typeid=40&minQ=1&typeid=11399&minQ=1&usesystem=30002187";

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(OrePrice);

TriPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
TriPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 34, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
PyrPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
PyrPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 35, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
MexPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
MexPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 36, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
IsoPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
IsoPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 37, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
NocPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
NocPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 38, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
MegPrAmarB.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Buy, StatType.Max);
MegPrAmarS.Text = GetStat(xdoc, 40, TranType.Sell, StatType.Max);
```

Here's a short demo (console app): https://dotnetfiddle.net/RlUCEq

Comment: this is worth an answer.

Comment: this makes sense to me, wasnt aware that i was able to xpath the type ID like shown, good stuff!!

Comment: @BicPen Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, don't do that. This is horrible.
You should use already existing Serialisation components from .NET.

here is an amazing [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

```
<AddressDetails>
    <HouseNo>4</HouseNo>
    <StreetName>Rohini</StreetName>
    <City>Delhi</City>
</AddressDetails>

public class AddressDetails
{ 
    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Street")] 
    public  string StreetName { get; set; } 
    [XmlElement("CityName")]
}

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    AddressDetails details = new AddressDetails();
    details.HouseNo = 4;
    details.StreeName = "Rohini";
    details.City = "Delhi";
    Serialize(details);
}   
static public void Serialize(AddressDetails details)
{ 
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddressDetails)); 
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, details); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: i know, it's annoying me looking at it, thanks for the example !!

Comment: this still doesnt really help with making it easier to manage.

Comment: @BicPen What do you mean easier to manage? What's hard about this?

Comment: well i have to do this another 5 times with 16 lots of boxes yet to fill >.> what your showing me doesnt look any easier

Comment: It is easier. The more changes you have and the more classes you have it will become easier to develop further, expand modify.
Just trust me on this one. All you are required to do for the next one is to create other classes that will be imported or exported to XML.